# Windows Deployment SErver TFTP connection issues

Tags: wireshark, firewall, tftp, wds

Having a strange issue with WDS, During the boot process, an I wanted to get some opinions.

What is happening is The TFTP boot process is failing with a with a PXE-E32 Time out error, during the boot process. The Boot server is on another subnet with DCHP coming from a Juniper firewall.

I have configured the bootserver and boot file options on the juniper firewall.

I have been able to verfiy that TFTP is allowed through the firewall, by making a direct connection with TFTPD to the exact same boot file (boot\x86\wdsnbp.com)

I did a wireshark trace when the workstation was pxe booting and saw not TFTP packets at all.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this one out we use a juniper srx 220 and we needed to configure the next server parameter as the wds server to alow the pxe boot process to complete